# My DatagridView loses data when I restart the application, how can I resolve this?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I currently have two forms. The first form has a dataGridView on it, the second form has six text boxes and a button. On the button click the information is taken from the text boxes and put into the dataGridView. The problem I am having is that when I exit the application and run the application again there is no data shown in the dataGridView. How can I resolve this?

Is there a way to save the information inputted into the dataGridView or would I have to make a data table and store the information from the text boxes in there and then use that as a data source for the dataGridView?

Comment: :do you have any database?

Answer (score 1):

As you said you could use a datatable to store the info of the textbox but when you will close the application you will still lose the info.

if you want to keep information from each time you ran you application you will need to save the info in a file or in a database

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I will probably go down the route of saving the information to a text file, how would I go about doing this? Would I need a save button on my 1st form?

Comment: @MaGiCo UK this simply depend if you need to validate info in the datagridview
if you don't you can simply save when this form is closed for example

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by validate info, do you mean check the info being received is the right type? If I did not need to validate my information, what code would I have to use to save the information when the form closes? Would this be done automatically or would I have to create a save button to do this.

Comment: @MaGiCo UK I mean if the user can input stuff in the dataGridView you would be better to validate those info. For the save button it really depend if you want it to be saved automaticly or manually triggered by the user. Sorry for my poor english

Comment: ok currently the information being put in the dataGridView is not being validated. I think it would be best if the information is saved automatically as it would be annoying to not press the save button and lose all of the data.

Comment: then id go for the save in the formclosing event

Comment: ok thanks im_a_noob, you wouldn't happen to know the code to make it save to a text file would you?

Comment: Basically just make yourself a patern (like a split ex : |) to be able to write and reread from the file. so something like 'foreach(DataGridViewRow row in [dgv name].rows)
{
   foreach(dgvcolumn c in row.column)
   {
       string += c.value
   }
}

then write that line to a file. for how to write in a file you can refert to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to use a database for saving data,or you can save your data in a `TXT` file and save them in file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a local DB to your project and bind the dataGridView to it.